# undefined reference to `main' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c, sqlite, gcc

I am trying to create a phonebook using sqlite, and I get compilation errors, I was able to debug a few syntax errors, but the problem I am now having is making sure that the following error is corrected.

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20):
```

I will appreciate explaining the error and providing some solution

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>

static int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName) {
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i<argc; i++) {
      printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
   }
   printf("...................................................\n");
   return 0;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   sqlite3 *db;
   char *zErrMsg = 0;
   int rc;
   char *sql;
   const char* data = "Callback function called";


if (argc == 3 && (0 == strcmp(argv[1], "-f"))) {
    if(argc == 1){

   rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);
     if( rc ) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
      return(0);
   } else {
   /* Create SQL statement */
   sql = "CREATE TABLE CONTACTS("  \
         "ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL," \
         "FIRSTNAME      TEXT    NOT NULL," \
         "LASTNAME       TEXT    NOT NULL," \
         "MOBILEPHONE       TEXT    NOT NULL," \
         "CITY            TEXT     NOT NULL," \
         "ADDRESS        CHAR(50)," \
         "COUNTRY         TEXT );";

   /* Execute SQL statement */
   rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
   if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
   fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
      sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
   } else {
      fprintf(stdout, "Table created successfully\n");
   }
   sqlite3_close(db);
   return 0;
  }
 }
 }
}
void MainMenu()
{
        int optn; // option value
        int valid; //check if option is valid
        system("clear");
      valid = 0;
        while( valid == 0 )
       {
       printf("---------------DELIMITER---------------\n");
       printf("Phone book Menu\n");
       printf("(1) Add new record to phone book\n");
       printf("(2) Search phone book\n");
       printf("(3) Update phone book\n");
       printf("(4) Delete record from phone book\n");
       printf("(5) Quit\n");
       printf("---------------DELIMITER---------------\n");
       printf("Please choose your operation: ");

                if(scanf("%d", &optn) == 1)
                {
                        if(optn > 0 && optn < 6)
                        {
                                valid = 1;
                        }else{
                                printf("Error: Invalid option selected, please try again\n\n");
                }

        }
        //start the operations
        if(optn == 1)
        {
            AddMenu();
        }else if (optn == 2)
        {

                SearchMenu();
        }else if (optn == 3)
        {
                UpdateMenu();
        }else if (optn == 4)
        {
                DeleteMenu();
        }else{
                exit(0);
        }
    }
}
//search menu
void SearchMenu()
{
        int optn; // option value
        int valid; //check if option is valid
        int display_search; //allow csv file export
        char ch; //repeat option value
        sqlite3 *db;
        char *zErrMsg = 0;
         int rc;
         char *sql;
         const char* data;

        printf("\tSearch PhoneBook\n");
        printf("================================\n\n");
        valid = 0;
        while( valid == 0 )
        {
                printf("Select a search option:\n");
                printf("-----------------------\n");
                printf(" 1) Display search result\n");
                printf(" 2) Back\n\n");
                printf("Choose an option: ");

                if(scanf("%d", &optn) == 1)
                {
                        if(optn > 0 && optn < 3)
                        {
                                valid = 1;
                        }else{
                                printf("Error: Invalid option selected, please try again\n\n");
                        }
                }
        //start the operations
        if(optn == 1)
        {
         sql = "SELECT * from CONTACTS";

   /* Execute SQL statement */
        rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg);
  if( rc != SQLITE_OK ) {
      fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
      sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
   } else {
      fprintf(stdout, "Operation done successfully\n");
   }
   sqlite3_close(db);
   return;
  }

}

}
void AddMenu()
{
char *sql;
        char statement[512];
        char *fname = malloc(50);
        char *lname = malloc(50);
        char *city= malloc(50);
        char *country= malloc(50);
        sqlite3 *db;
        char *zErrMsg = 0;
         int rc;
        printf("Enter the First Name: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]s", fname);


        printf("Enter the Last Name: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]s", lname);


        printf("Enter the Mobile Phone: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]s", mobile);

        printf("Enter the City: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]s", city);

          printf("Enter the Country: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]s", country);

     //run SQL Statements

        sql = "INSERT INTO CONTACT (FirstName,LastName,MobilePhone,City,Country) "  \
         "VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s' );";

   /* Execute SQL statement */
   rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);

   if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
      fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
      sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
   } else {
      fprintf(stdout, "Records created successfully\n");
   }
   sqlite3_close(db);
   return;
}
void UpdateMenu()
{
char id;
int valid;
char *fname = malloc(50);
char *lname = malloc(50);
char *mobile= malloc(20);
char *city= malloc(50);
char *country= malloc(50);
char statement[512];
char values_cut[512];
char fname_out[50];
char lname_out[50];
char mobile_out[20];
char city_out[50];
char country_out[50];
sqlite3 *db;
char *zErrMsg = 0;
int rc;
char *sql;
const char* data;

if(do_search(0) == 0){

        valid = 0;
        while( valid == 0 )
        {
                printf("Enter the Number you want to update: ");

                if(scanf("%s", &id) == 1)
                        {
                                if(id > 0 )
                                {
                                        valid = 1;

                                        printf("\nUpdate the values, press enter if you do not want to change a field\n");
                                        printf("---------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

                                        //get the update values
                                        printf("Enter the First Name: ");
                                        if((scanf("%[^\n]s", fname) != 0)){
                                                snprintf(fname_out, sizeof fname_out, "FirstName='%s',",fname);
                                        }else{
                                                snprintf(fname_out,sizeof fname_out, "");
                                        }
                                        fname = fname_out;


                                        printf("Enter the Last Name: ");
                                        if((scanf("%[^\n]s", lname)!=0)){
                                                snprintf(lname_out,sizeof lname_out, "LastName='%s',",lname);
                                        }else{
                                                snprintf(lname_out,sizeof lname_out, "");
                                        }
                                        lname=lname_out;


                                     printf("Enter the Mobile Phone: ");
                                        if((scanf("%[^\n]s", mobile)!=0)){
                                                snprintf(mobile_out,sizeof mobile_out, "MobilePhone='%s',",mobile);
                                        }else{
                                                snprintf(mobile_out,sizeof mobile_out, "");
                                        }
                                        mobile=mobile_out;


                                        printf("Enter the City: ");
                                        if((scanf("%[^\n]s", city)!=0)){
                                                snprintf(city_out,sizeof city_out, "City='%s',",city);
                                        }else{
                                                snprintf(city_out,sizeof city_out, "");
                                        }
                                        city=city_out;


                                        printf("Enter the Country: ");
                                        if((scanf("%[^\n]s", country)!=0)){
                                                snprintf(country_out,sizeof country_out, "Country='%s',",country);
                                                                   }else{
                                                snprintf(country_out,sizeof country_out, "");
                                        }
                                        country=country_out;


                                        //remove the last comma from the query
                                        snprintf(values_cut,sizeof values_cut, "%s%s%s%s%s",fname,lname,mobile,city,country);

                                                }
                                        }

/* Create merged SQL statement */
   sql = "UPDATE CONTACT set %s where ID=%s";
         "SELECT * from CONTACT  where ID=%s";

   /* Execute SQL statement */
   rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg);

   if( rc != SQLITE_OK ) {
      fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
      sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
   } else {
      fprintf(stdout, "Operation done successfully\n");
   }
   sqlite3_close(db);
   return;
}

}


}
//Delete menu
void DeleteMenu()
{
        int valid;
        int id, good;
        char *sql;
        char statement[512];
        sqlite3 *db;
        char *zErrMsg = 0;
        int rc;
        const char* data;
        int optn;
        //search first
        if(do_search(0)==0){

        valid = 0;
        while( valid == 0 )
        {
                printf("Enter the number you want to delete: ");

                if(scanf("%s", &id) == 1)
                        {
                                if(id > 0 )
                                {
                                        valid = 1;
/* Create merged SQL statement */
   sql = "DELETE from CONTACT where ID=%s; " \
         "SELECT * from CONTACT";

   /* Execute SQL statement */
   rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg);

   if( rc != SQLITE_OK ) {
      fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
      sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
   } else {
      fprintf(stdout, "Operation done successfully\n");
   }
   sqlite3_close(db);
   return;
      }
   }while(optn!=5);
 }
}
}
}

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>

static int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName) {
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i<argc; i++) {
      printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
   }
   printf("...................................................\n");
   return 0;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   sqlite3 *db;
   char *zErrMsg = 0;
   int rc;
   char *sql;
   const char* data = "Callback function called";


if (argc == 3 && (0 == strcmp(argv[1], "-f"))) {
    if(argc == 1){

   rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);
     if( rc ) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
      return(0);
   } else {
   /* Create SQL statement */
   sql = "CREATE TABLE CONTACTS("  \
         "ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL," \
         "FIRSTNAME      TEXT    NOT NULL," \
         "LASTNAME       TEXT    NOT NULL," \
         "MOBILEPHONE       TEXT    NOT NULL," \
         "CITY            TEXT     NOT NULL," \
         "ADDRESS        CHAR(50)," \
         "COUNTRY         TEXT );";

   /* Execute SQL statement */
   rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
   if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
   fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
      sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
   } else {
      fprintf(stdout, "Table created successfully\n");
   }
   sqlite3_close(db);
   return 0;
  }
 }
 }
}
void MainMenu()
{
        int optn; // option value
        int valid; //check if option is valid
        system("clear");
      valid = 0;
        while( valid == 0 )
       {
       printf("---------------DELIMITER---------------\n");
       printf("Phone book Menu\n");
       printf("(1) Add new record to phone book\n");
       printf("(2) Search phone book\n");
       printf("(3) Update phone book\n");
       printf("(4) Delete record from phone book\n");
       printf("(5) Quit\n");
       printf("---------------DELIMITER---------------\n");
       printf("Please choose your operation: ");

                if(scanf("%d", &optn) == 1)
                {
                        if(optn > 0 && optn < 6)
                        {
                                valid = 1;
                        }else{
                                printf("Error: Invalid option selected, please try again\n\n");
                }

        }
        //start the operations
        if(optn == 1)
        {
            AddMenu();
        }else if (optn == 2)
        {

                SearchMenu();
        }else if (optn == 3)
        {
                UpdateMenu();
        }else if (optn == 4)
        {
                DeleteMenu();
        }else{
                exit(0);
        }
    }
}
//search menu
void SearchMenu()
{
        int optn; // option value
        int valid; //check if option is valid
        int display_search; //allow csv file export
        char ch; //repeat option value
        sqlite3 *db;
        char *zErrMsg = 0;
         int rc;
         char *sql;
         const char* data;

        printf("\tSearch PhoneBook\n");
        printf("================================\n\n");
        valid = 0;
        while( valid == 0 )
        {
                printf("Select a search option:\n");
                printf("-----------------------\n");
                printf(" 1) Display search result\n");
                printf(" 2) Back\n\n");
                printf("Choose an option: ");

                if(scanf("%d", &optn) == 1)
                {
                        if(optn > 0 && optn < 3)
                        {
                                valid = 1;
                        }else{
                                printf("Error: Invalid option selected, please try again\n\n");
                        }
                }
        //start the operations
        if(optn == 1)
        {
         sql = "SELECT * from CONTACTS";

   /* Execute SQL statement */
        rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg);
  if( rc != SQLITE_OK ) {
      fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
      sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
   } else {
      fprintf(stdout, "Operation done successfully\n");
   }
   sqlite3_close(db);
   return;
  }

}

}
void AddMenu()
{
char *sql;
        char statement[512];
        char *fname = malloc(50);
        char *lname = malloc(50);
        char *city= malloc(50);
        char *country= malloc(50);
        sqlite3 *db;
        char *zErrMsg = 0;
         int rc;
        printf("Enter the First Name: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]s", fname);


        printf("Enter the Last Name: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]s", lname);


        printf("Enter the Mobile Phone: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]s", mobile);

        printf("Enter the City: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]s", city);

          printf("Enter the Country: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]s", country);

     //run SQL Statements

        sql = "INSERT INTO CONTACT (FirstName,LastName,MobilePhone,City,Country) "  \
         "VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s' );";

   /* Execute SQL statement */
   rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);

   if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
      fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
      sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
   } else {
      fprintf(stdout, "Records created successfully\n");
   }
   sqlite3_close(db);
   return;
}
void UpdateMenu()
{
char id;
int valid;
char *fname = malloc(50);
char *lname = malloc(50);
char *mobile= malloc(20);
char *city= malloc(50);
char *country= malloc(50);
char statement[512];
char values_cut[512];
char fname_out[50];
char lname_out[50];
char mobile_out[20];
char city_out[50];
char country_out[50];
sqlite3 *db;
char *zErrMsg = 0;
int rc;
char *sql;
const char* data;

if(do_search(0) == 0){

        valid = 0;
        while( valid == 0 )
        {
                printf("Enter the Number you want to update: ");

                if(scanf("%s", &id) == 1)
                        {
                                if(id > 0 )
                                {
                                        valid = 1;

                                        printf("\nUpdate the values, press enter if you do not want to change a field\n");
                                        printf("---------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

                                        //get the update values
                                        printf("Enter the First Name: ");
                                        if((scanf("%[^\n]s", fname) != 0)){
                                                snprintf(fname_out, sizeof fname_out, "FirstName='%s',",fname);
                                        }else{
                                                snprintf(fname_out,sizeof fname_out, "");
                                        }
                                        fname = fname_out;


                                        printf("Enter the Last Name: ");
                                        if((scanf("%[^\n]s", lname)!=0)){
                                                snprintf(lname_out,sizeof lname_out, "LastName='%s',",lname);
                                        }else{
                                                snprintf(lname_out,sizeof lname_out, "");
                                        }
                                        lname=lname_out;


                                     printf("Enter the Mobile Phone: ");
                                        if((scanf("%[^\n]s", mobile)!=0)){
                                                snprintf(mobile_out,sizeof mobile_out, "MobilePhone='%s',",mobile);
                                        }else{
                                                snprintf(mobile_out,sizeof mobile_out, "");
                                        }
                                        mobile=mobile_out;


                                        printf("Enter the City: ");
                                        if((scanf("%[^\n]s", city)!=0)){
                                                snprintf(city_out,sizeof city_out, "City='%s',",city);
                                        }else{
                                                snprintf(city_out,sizeof city_out, "");
                                        }
                                        city=city_out;


                                        printf("Enter the Country: ");
                                        if((scanf("%[^\n]s", country)!=0)){
                                                snprintf(country_out,sizeof country_out, "Country='%s',",country);
                                                                   }else{
                                                snprintf(country_out,sizeof country_out, "");
                                        }
                                        country=country_out;


                                        //remove the last comma from the query
                                        snprintf(values_cut,sizeof values_cut, "%s%s%s%s%s",fname,lname,mobile,city,country);

                                                }
                                        }

/* Create merged SQL statement */
   sql = "UPDATE CONTACT set %s where ID=%s";
         "SELECT * from CONTACT  where ID=%s";

   /* Execute SQL statement */
   rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg);

   if( rc != SQLITE_OK ) {
      fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
      sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
   } else {
      fprintf(stdout, "Operation done successfully\n");
   }
   sqlite3_close(db);
   return;
}

}


}
//Delete menu
void DeleteMenu()
{
        int valid;
        int id, good;
        char *sql;
        char statement[512];
        sqlite3 *db;
        char *zErrMsg = 0;
        int rc;
        const char* data;
        int optn;
        //search first
        if(do_search(0)==0){

        valid = 0;
        while( valid == 0 )
        {
                printf("Enter the number you want to delete: ");

                if(scanf("%s", &id) == 1)
                        {
                                if(id > 0 )
                                {
                                        valid = 1;
/* Create merged SQL statement */
   sql = "DELETE from CONTACT where ID=%s; " \
         "SELECT * from CONTACT";

   /* Execute SQL statement */
   rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg);

   if( rc != SQLITE_OK ) {
      fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
      sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
   } else {
      fprintf(stdout, "Operation done successfully\n");
   }
   sqlite3_close(db);
   return;
      }
   }while(optn!=5);
 }
}
}
}
```

when i  compile this c code on putty using

```
gcc insertno.c -o insertno -lsqlite3
```

i get this error below, solution will be much appreciated.thanks

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20):
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20):
```

Comment: this function: `callback()` is missing the trailing closing brace '}'`   Your compiler should have told you about that.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )

Comment: the posted code when passed to the compiler, produces a LONG string of warning and error messages.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code. Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}',  suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.  3) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent).  4) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: variable (and parameter) names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both).

Comment: regarding: `snprintf(fname_out,sizeof fname_out, "");` (and similar statements)  a zero length format string is not valid

Comment: regarding: `if((scanf("%[^\n]s", lname)!=0))` (and similar statements) this will not properly check if the call to `scanf()` was successful.  (`scanf()` can return `EOF`, amongst other things.)  suggest: `if((scanf("%[^\n]s", lname) == 1 ))`  and the `s` will not be in the input stream, so the input operation will stop when it expects the `s`  Note: the input format specifier `%[^\n]` is complete,  Strongly suggest removing the trailing `s`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) insert appropriate horizontal spacing: inside parens, after commas, after semicolons, around C operators.

Comment: regarding: `sql = "UPDATE CONTACT set %s where ID=%s";
         "SELECT * from CONTACT  where ID=%s";`  the trailing `;` on the first line ends the statement, so the second line results in a compile error.  Suggest removing the trailing `;` from the first line

Comment: regarding: `sql = "DELETE from CONTACT where ID=%s; " \
         "SELECT * from CONTACT";`  the backslash is not needed, and should be removed

Comment: regarding: `static int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName) {`  the next line in the code should be: `(void)NotUsed;`

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%[^\n]s", mobile);`  The variable `mobile` is not in scope so this line does not compile.  Also, the format string has a spurious trailing `s`.   The trailing `s` must be removed

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: the posted code fails to compile There are some dozens of error and warning messages from the compiler!   When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 20, 50, 512, etc.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, when using the format specifiers: '%[...]' and '%s', always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer.  These format specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This is to avoid any buffer overflow.  Such overflow is undefined behavior and can/will lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: the function: `do_search()` is not defined anywhere in the posted code

Comment: for ease of readability, please honor the right hand page margin (usually column 72 or 80)

Comment: regarding: `if (argc == 3 && (0 == strcmp(argv[1], "-f")))
    {
        if(argc == 1)`  the value of `argc` cannot be both 3 and 1 so the body of the nested `if()` will never be executed.

Comment: if `argc` ==  3 and `argv[1]` == '-f`, then the code does nothing

Comment: the posted code is missing all the prototype statements for the sub functions in the file.

Comment: the posted code contains two copies of the code, Please correct

Comment: the posted code never calls any of the sub functions because the very first `if()` in `main()` may (or may not) be entered and even if entered, the second `if()` will NEVER be entered.  So over 400 lines of code and it does absolutely nothing.

Comment: can you assist with sorting the error and highlight them so i dont make mistake next time because i am new to c programming and i find it extremely difficult to understand few syntax. thanks

Comment: the posted code contains the problem with the missing closing brace '}' at the end of the callback function  After fixing that problem, then the logic of the code is not correct,  You do realize (I hope) that a variable cannot contain two different values at the same time.   Since your just starting with C, strongly suggest programs that are short and simple.  a 400+ line program is NOT short and simple.

Comment: when you are having a problem with the syntax for a function, use google with: `syntax for ... in c`  or `examples for ... in c` or `how to use ... in c`  Then for the details of a function, read the associated MAN page.  On linux, that would be: `man ...`   (note: the `...` are where you type in the name of the function.  The C language only has about 7 statements.  It is how those statements are put together that counts.  There are LOTS of 'helper' functions in the libraries.  You should read some tutorial about the C library functions.

Answer (score 3):

The body of your function `callback()` has not been properly closed off.

```
static int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName) {
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i<argc; i++) {
      printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
   }
   printf("...................................................\n");
   return 0;
} // THIS WAS MISSING
```

The reason GCC didn't flag an error when it encountered a function definition within the `callback()` function is that GCC has an extension called [nested functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html).

Comment: If ever you wanted an argument why that GCC extension is pernicious, that mass of code makes a great case study.  It should require explicit enablement (e.g. `-fnested-functions`); it should never be enabled by default.